# SQL Subquery not working properly

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a table structure like

```
Files                     Latest_Update
-------------------      ------------------------------
Fid - Name - Type -      l-id  - c_name - c_val - Fid -
-------------------      ------------------------------
1   - D1   - xls  -       1    - text1  - hello -  1  -
-------------------      ------------------------------

  Revisions
------------------------------
r-id  - c_name - c_val - Fid -
------------------------------
 1    - text1  - bye   -  1  -
------------------------------
```

i am trying to get all values of text1 control either in `Revisions` or `Latest_Update` 
here is what i have tried

```
SELECT RS.c_name. RS.c_val from (SELECT Revisions.c_name, Revisions.c_val, Latest_Update.c_name,Latest_Update.c_val
From Revisions
INNER JOIN Latest_Update on Revisions.Fid = Latest_Updates.Fid) AS RS
```

but its not working , i need the result to be something like

```
Result
------------------------------
- c_name - c_val - Fid -
------------------------------
- text1  - Hello-  1   -
------------------------------
- text1  - bye   -  1  -
------------------------------
```

**I am Using MS ACCESS 2010**

Comment: Should `RS.c_name. RS.c_val` be separated by a coma instead of a dot? What is the result you geT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think union is the solution. Something like..

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT Revisions.c_name, Revisions.c_val, Revisions.Fid
  FROM Revisions
UNION ALL
SELECT Latest_Update.c_name,Latest_Update.c_val, Latest_Update.c_name,Latest_Update.Fid
FROM Latest_Update
) RS
<if needed add Where Condition>
ORDER BY RS.Fid
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use union instead of inner join ...

```
select * from (
select c_name,c_val,fid from Revisions
union 
select c_name,c_val,fid from Latest_updates)x
where fid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c_name, c_val, Fid FROM Latest_Update
WHERE c_name = 'text1'
UNION ALL
SELECT c_name, c_val, Fid FROM Revisions
WHERE c_name = 'text1'
```